# Make multiple predictions with one network at once - keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, prediction, object-detection

I'm using Keras for a sliding window object detection system. This naturally requires the ability to do many, many classifications quickly. Unfortunately, Keras's `model.predict()` function has a significant overhead and takes longer to load? preprocess the data? who knows, than it does to do the actual network processing. I know because I've tried removing layers, etc. and it makes almost no difference to the time spent in a `model.predict()` call.

So basically what I'm looking for is a way to use one network and run predictions on several inputs at once. Not necessarily in separate threads, but without returning to my code. Is anyone aware of such a technique?

Comment: model.predict can already take multiple inputs (in the first dimension), so I am not sure what is the problem.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro it can indeed take multiple inputs, but as far as I know the network has to be designed to take multiple. Please correct me if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You can process several samples at once using batching.

Comment: Predicting is pretty much like training. You train with lots of samples in a batch, and you predict with lots of samples in a batch. No difference.

Comment: @DanielMöller When I pass it a list of Numpy arrays, it gives me the following error: https://hastebin.com/iliqohokom.pas Is there some configuration change I need to make to process a batch?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro see comment above

Comment: You must pass a single numpy array, not a list of numpy arrays. If you've got variable lengths, there is no choice, but separating arrays for each length and predicting each of these arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144191/keras-misinterprets-training-data-shape/46146146#46146146

Comment: @DanielMöller thank you! I had the incorrect number of dimensions and had to squeeze it. Works now! Feel free to add it as an answer, I will accept.